# ubuntu like lightdm in arch linux

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, configuration, desktop-environment, lightdm

I have just installed archlinux on a virtual machine and I managed to install lightdm by following the instructions given in

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM

[https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager#Modify_default_display_manager)

but lightdm looks like this [image: default lightdm looks]

But I want it to look like the default one in ubuntu 
[image: Ubuntu default lightdm]

How can that be done ?

Ps: I am running xfce4 as the desktop Environment

Comment: If nobody has a better idea, you could boot an Ubuntu Live CD and look at its configuration file. (I am assuming LightDM ist what Ubuntu uses?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[The ArchWiki looks dead currently, so I don't know what is contained in the instructions you linked to.]*

To change the looks of LightDM, you need to install a theme and configure it. [This page](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=40708&comments=all) suggests that the relevant Arch packages might be **lightdm-unity-greeter** or **lightdm-webkit-greeter**.

Comment: The wiki is up now , I'll try installing the packages you mentioned .

Comment: I managed to Install it , But I don't know how to activate it , Any Ideas ?

Comment: According to [this](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=40708&comments=all), the configuration file on Arch is named `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. And, for example, [this blog entry](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2010/07/lightdm.html) suggests how a simple config file may look like (google or read documentation for more).

Comment: on newer versions run these commands: `echo "[SeatDefaults]" | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` and `echo "greeter-session=unity-greeter" | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf`